# Python, Google App Engine error: assert type(data) is StringType,"write() argument must be string"

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm learning Google App Engine right now with a book 'Using Google App Engine by Charles Severance'.

I am on chapter 6 and so far I have made `app.yaml`, `index.py`, `index.html` in templates folder and the CSS file in the static folder.

My `index.py` looks like this:

```
import os
import wsgiref.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
      def get(self):
          path=self.request.path
          temp=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__, 'templates' + path)
          if not os.path.isfile(temp):
             temp=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__, 'templates/index.html')

          self.response.out.write(template.render(temp,{}))

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', MainHandler)], debug=True)
    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)

if __name == '__main__':
   main()
```

Why am I am getting this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 202, in write
    **assert type(data) is StringType,"write() argument must be string"**

AssertionError: write() argument must be string
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this exact error recently as well, due to some old Google App Engine sample code.  My problem was in the `doRender()` function, where the `outstr` object was a `django.utils.safestring.SafeUnicode` object, and thus the `write()` function was complaining.  So I passed it through `unicode()` to end up with a unicode object that `write()` was okay with.

```
def doRender(handler, tname="index.html", values={}):
    temp = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                        'templates/' + tname)
    if not os.path.isfile(temp):
        return False

    # Make a copy of the dictionary and add the path
    newval = dict(values)
    newval['path'] = handler.request.path

    outstr = template.render(temp, newval)
    handler.response.out.write(unicode(outstr))
    return True
```

Comment: I tried unicode, but didn't work out somehow. Then I tried put str to cast the output as a string, then it worked! Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

Line 2: change `import wsgiref.appengine.ext import webapp` to `import wsgiref`.

Line 9: add an `)` after `__file__`

Line 11: add an `)` after `__file__`

Line 19: change `__name` to `__name__`

These are all basic syntax errors. You just copied from the book wrong. Always run new code through dev_appserver.py, the development server provided by the App Engine SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I actually typed right on the text editor, but copied very wrong on my post. I should pay more attention in detail for sure! Thanks again.